# AR(2) model with and without mean

Tags: r, autoregressive-models

I am fitting a time series data by AR(2). After I subtracted the mean of the whole dataset, I expect the command `include.mean = T` and `include.mean = F` to give the same zero intercept. However, it seems its not the case. Could anyone explain why?

The following is the code:

```
sspar2 <- arima(ssp-mean(ssp$X101), order=c(2,0,0), include.mean = F, method = "ML")
```

with output

```
Call:
arima(x = ssp - mean(ssp$X101), order = c(2, 0, 0), include.mean = F, method = "ML")

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2
      1.3998  -0.7094
s.e.  0.0707   0.0701

sigma^2 estimated as 227.1:  log likelihood = -410.29,  aic = 826.59
```

and

```
sspar2 <- arima(ssp-mean(ssp$X101), order=c(2,0,0), include.mean = T, method = "ML")
sspar2
```

with output

```
Call:
arima(x = ssp - mean(ssp$X101), order = c(2, 0, 0), include.mean = T, method = "ML")

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2  intercept
      1.3999  -0.7092     1.1877
s.e.  0.0706   0.0701     4.9039

sigma^2 estimated as 227:  log likelihood = -410.26,  aic = 828.53
```

Answer (score 1):

From R documentation, include.mean definition is "Should the ARMA model include a mean/intercept term? The default is TRUE for undifferenced series, and it is ignored for ARIMA models with differencing."
You have an undifferenced series as your d=0 in Arima(p,d,q). Therefore you have an intercept term unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: But technically for undifferenced models, the coefficient $\phi$ should remain the same for including the intercept and not including intercept term? We haven't cover things about differencing. So I'm not sure if this question makes sense. It seems that the models are a little different in terms of the coefficients. What caused this?

Comment: The coefficients should not remain the same for models with and without the intercept term .  There is a lot of information in textbooks and online about why that is the case, including https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-a-linear-regression-model.  Differencing in an ARIMA context is not subtracting values from the mean as you did in your example.  Rather it is  1) sequential differencing, value at time t minus value at t-1, or 2) periodic differencing such as year-over-year, or the same hour today minus same hour yesterday, etc.